# What does "new" do in Java w.r.t. class loader?

Tags: java, classloader

I cannot easily find it in JLS/JVMSpec, nor in SO. I'm sure it must've been asked...

So, what does "new" do actually? Suppose we instantiate a class B in A:

```
class A {
    // ...
    new B();
    // ...
}
```

Is this equivalent to

```
class A {
    // ...
    A.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("B's canonical name").newInstance();
    // ...
}
```

?

Does it, or does it not work like that in every environment?

I'd be grateful if you can point me to the appropriate chapter in JLS/JVMSpec. Thanks!

Edit: surely we can't call `B.class.getCanonicalName()` in `loadClass()` call, since B's not loaded yet. JVM has to resolve the name based on the import statement.

Comment: javap is your friend. Also a breakpoint the static initializer of B will provide some insight.

Comment: @Hermal: `javap` doesn't really tell you a lot, since the bytecode is still pretty high-level and the actual actions taking during instantiation are not visible at that level.

Comment: @MaDa: *one* reason why it can't work is that `B.class` would require the class to be loaded, so your pseudo-code would be caught in a catch-22: it needs the class to be loaded in order to be able to load it.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> Is this equivalent to
>
> ```
> class A {
>     // ...
>     A.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("B's canonical name").newInstance();
>     // ...
> }
> ```
>
> ?

No, not always.

Class loading is performed only once for a given namespace, unless the `Class` in question has been previously unloaded. Therefore, the equivalent expression `A.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("B's canonical name")` will be executed only once in most scenarios. In other words, if you have two expressions - `new A()`, the `loadClass` will be performed only once.

Invocation of a constructor is treated as a method invocation by the JVM, but this requires the cooperation of a Java compiler. The JVM and the compiler have to adhere to section 3.9 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification, which states:

> **3.9 Specially Named Initialization Methods**
>
> At the level of the Java virtual machine, every constructor (§2.12)
>   appears as an instance initialization method that has the special name
>   `<init>`. This name is supplied by a compiler. Because the name `<init>`
>   is not a valid identifier, it cannot be used directly in a program
>   written in the Java programming language. Instance initialization
>   methods may be invoked only within the Java virtual machine by the
>   *invokespecial* instruction, and they may be invoked only on
>   uninitialized class instances. An instance initialization method takes
>   on the access permissions (§2.7.4) of the constructor from which it
>   was derived.
>
> A class or interface has at most one class or interface initialization
>   method and is initialized (§2.17.4) by invoking that method. The
>   initialization method of a class or interface is static and takes no
>   arguments. It has the special name `<clinit>`. This name is supplied by
>   a compiler. Because the name `<clinit>` is not a valid identifier, it
>   cannot be used directly in a program written in the Java programming
>   language. Class and interface initialization methods are invoked
>   implicitly by the Java virtual machine; they are never invoked
>   directly from any Java virtual machine instruction, but are invoked
>   only indirectly as part of the class initialization process.

This section assumes that the `Class` object pertaining to the class in question is available to the current thread. Once the `Class` object is available, the method `<init>` corresponding to the constructor with the right set of arguments, will be invoked.

The question of which classloader will be used to load the class, if not already loaded, is a bit different, and has nothing to do with the new keyword. It depends on how one class references another i.e. does a symbolic reference need to be resolved in the runtime constant pool? The behavior in this context is defined in Section 5.3 of the Java Virtual Machine Specification:

> **5.3 Creation and Loading**
>
> Creation of a class or interface C denoted by the name N consists of
>   the construction in the method area of the Java virtual machine
>   (§3.5.4) of an implementation-specific internal representation of C.
>   Class or interface creation is triggered by another class or interface
>   D, which references C through its runtime constant pool.
>
> ...
>
> The Java virtual machine uses one of three procedures to create class
>   or interface C denoted by N:
>
> - If N denotes a nonarray class or an interface, one of the two following methods is used to load and thereby create C :
>
>   - If D was defined by the bootstrap class loader, then the bootstrap
>       class loader initiates loading of C (§5.3.1).
>   - If D was defined by a user-defined class loader, then that same
>       user-defined class loader initiates loading of C (§5.3.2).
> - Otherwise N denotes an array class. An array class is created directly by the Java virtual machine (§5.3.3), not by a class loader.
>     However, the defining class loader of D is used in the process of
>     creating array class C.

Note the sentence - `If D was defined by a user-defined class loader, then that same user-defined class loader initiates loading of C` in the above quote. In the context of the expression `new A()`, the classloader that loaded the enclosing class will be responsible for loading `A` in accordance with the VM Spec; this is of course, assuming that the enclosing class is not loaded by the bootstrap classloader.

Comment: Many thanks, that's the answer I was looking for. And since API doc for ClassLoader says that "every Class object contains a reference to the ClassLoader that defined it", then A.class.getClassLoader() will initiate loading B (with respect to all conditions mentioned above).

Answer (score 3):

To follow up on my comment, a line like

```
new A()
```

translates to

```
0:  new #2; //class A
3:  dup
4:  invokespecial   #3; //Method A."<init>":()V
7:  pop
```

And the stacktrace is:

```
  [1] java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run (URLClassLoader.java:202)
  [2] java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged (native method)
  [3] java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass (URLClassLoader.java:190)
  [4] sun.misc.Launcher$ExtClassLoader.findClass (Launcher.java:229)
  [5] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:307)
  [6] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:296)
  [7] sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass (Launcher.java:301)
  [8] java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass (ClassLoader.java:248)
  [9] Loader.main (Loader.java:11)
```

So I guess you were pretty close in your guess.

Comment: Note that the bytecode you quoted is **not** the only bytecode that gets generated by `new A()`! There's also a `new` bytecode.

Comment: OK, but what we *don't* see here is why URLClassLoader is being chosen. I know - because it's the default in a stand-alone java program. But how does the JVM know?

Comment: @HemalPandya Not that I succumbed to conspiracy theories, but does line 8 really prove that "loadClass" was called on the class loader obtained by Loader.class.getClassLoader(), and not some-JVM-object-storing-appropriate-class-loader? I still fail to see this part.

Comment: @MaDa there is nothing there to prove how `ClassLoader` instance was identified. I guess we only have the spec to go by.

Answer (score -1):

I've found this link that mainly explains the concept of the "new" operator in Java. The main idea for me is this phrase:

["(..) The new operator instantiates a class by allocating memory for a new object and returning a reference to that memory. The new operator also invokes the object constructor. (..)"](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/objectcreation.html)

I think that three things should be considered:

1. The "new" operator is common in every environment but due to developers need for it. In Java's case the "new" operator also allocates the memory space for the object.
2. Sometimes (in older compilers) it was not available and all declarations had to be made "the long way". So for retro-compatibility sake both statements are equivalent.
3. There is always the case were you may need to override the "loadClass" or the "getClassLoader()"

["(..)Even though Java's new keyword is central to the language, there may be better ways of getting the job done.(..)"](http://drdobbs.com/184405016)

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: You likely have missed the "with respect to class loader" part of my question. Besides, it is likely that a person asking class loader question already read Java Tutorial, and not just a moment ago.

Comment: BTW, what "old compilers" are you talking about? The "new" operator exists from the dawn of Java.

Comment: @Mada I once used some simple ones (old ones) that did not have the "new" operand, that is why I used the long expression. Anyway the question has been answered with great explanation so that is done.