# Does every "new" result in at least one Classloader.loadClass invocation

Tags: java

I noticed that we can set a Thread's context classloader at will. Does it mean that every `new` results in the context classloader's loadClass getting called?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, `loadClass()` will only be invoked once, the first time the class is accessed.  (This will not necessarily happen on `new()`, it may happen if you try to access a `static` member of the class.)

In every subsequent access of the class, `loadClass()` will not be invoked.

That's because every time the class is needed, the ClassLoader invokes `findClass()` internally, which tries to find an already loaded class, so if the class has already been loaded, the ClassLoader refrains from invoking `loadClass()` again.

Comment: Thanks. So every "new" results in a findClass invocation?

Comment: @androidguy Not necessarily. The JIT might compile code, and inline it, and *maybe* that could include whatever new() does. But that is a bit of guessing here. In any case: asking the classloader for "is that class already loaded" is for sure not for free, but still rather cheap compared to other things that happen here.

Answer (score 0):

Class loading by ClassLoaders can be implemented to **eagerly load** a class as soon as another class references it or **lazy load** the class until a need of class initialization occurs but you should be aware that the behavior might not exactly the same as **new** in some scenarios and might be the same in others.  If Class is loaded before its actually being used it can sit inside before being initialized. this might vary from JVM to JVM, but its guaranteed by JLS that a class will be loaded when there is a need of static initialization.

as also explained in [What does "new" do in Java w.r.t. class loader?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7709983/what-does-new-do-in-java-w-r-t-class-loader):

> Class loading is performed only **once** for a given namespace, unless the
>   Class in question has been previously unloaded. Therefore, the
>   equivalent expression **A.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("B's
>   canonical name")** will be executed only once in most scenarios. In
>   other words, if you have two expressions - new A(), the loadClass will
>   be performed only once.

Comment: Thanks. The thing that puzzles me is that because you can arbitrarily set the Thread's context classloader any time during execution, it's probably not possible to eagerly load any class referenced by a given class, because the first thing that I might be doing in every method may be switch the classloader to something weird such as a child first classloader that loads classes from a url or a DB or some arbitrary file system location. That means every new must at least ask the classloader to check whether a class has been loaded or not.